# meaning of: putting attributes into source to prevent the need for iteration?

Tags: clang

What does it mean when the attributes are placed in source order to prevent the need for repetition? For example in this block they are not in source order so what would need to be done?

```
  for (auto *Attr : D->getAttrs()) {
    SourceLoc AttrLoc = Attr->getRangeWithAt().Start;
    if (AttrLoc.isValid() && SM.isBeforeInBuffer(AttrLoc, SL))
        SL = AttrLoc;
  }
```

Comment: I don't know, what's an Attr? And isn't this a question about Attrs, not about C++?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the code snippet I see that you are talking about the Clang API. Most likely the source order means the order in which attributes appear in a source file. You can put them in this order by sorting on source location (represented by `SourceLoc`). Not sure what is meant by "preventing the need for repetition". I'd expect each attribute have a unique source location and even if there were duplicates, they would have different locations.

Comment: Sorry, yeah meant iteration. Thanks